# Android Back Button error

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

first Question is the Question_oceans  see code below.  trying to have user note that it can not get "Prevoius" question when button is pressed because it was the first question"  im getting an error.

```
private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void lastQuestion(boolean userPressedPrevious) {
    boolean answerIsYes = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    int messageQuesId = 0;

    if (userPressedPrevious == answerIsYes) {
        messageQuesId = R.string.not_previous;
    } else {
        updateQuestion();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, messageQuesId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    int messageResId = 0;

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }

    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
            lastQuestion(true);
        }
    });
    updateQuestion();

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    updateQuestion();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you're encountering an error, please tell us what the error message says, and which line it occurs on.

Comment: Please post the error message output from `LogCat` - it will make debugging far simpler.

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process:com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz, 
                                                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                    atandroid.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1334)
                                                                                    atandroid.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:379)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a try catch statement. If you run it again, you will probably see a logcat error telling you what the issue it. In catch, you could make a Toast saying, "Sorry, previous question not available". Good luck!